Is there a shortcut for python docstring to document implicit raised exception?
I'm working on a few python modules whose methods (by design) don't catch exceptions from functions called in their bodies. As far as I understand the results of my research, you should document any relevant exceptions in docstring :raises ...: blocks, in my case to primarily help users or their IDEs, not for automated documentation.
As given in the sample below, I'd have to repeat the :raises ...: blocks in several methods with the same information:
def myFunction(param1, param2):
  """
  :param str param1: first parameter...
  :param int param2: second parameter...
  :return None:
  :raises MyException1: in case...
  :raises MyException2: (from myFunction2) in case...
  :raises ValueError: (from myFunction3) in case...
  """
  if param1 is None:
    raise MyException1
  
  myFunction2(param1, param2)
  
def myFunction2(param1, param2):
  """
  :param str param1: first parameter...
  :param int param2: second parameter...
  :return void:
  :raises MyException2: in case...
  :raises ValueError: (from myFunction3) in case...
  """
  if param2 is None:
    raise MyException2
  
  myFunction3(param1)
  
def myFunction3(param):
  """
  :param str param: parameter...
  :return None:
  :raises ValueError: in case...
  """
  if param is None:
    raise ValueError

Is there a way to say in myFunction1 "here could be raised: myException1 and all exceptions from myFunction2 recursively" and so on in myFunction2?
I.e.:
def myFunction(param1, param2):
  """
  :param str param1: first parameter...
  :param int param2: second parameter...
  :return None:
  :raises MyException1: in case...
  :raisesfrom myFunction2: ??? does anything like this exists, or some other way ???
  """
  if param1 is None:
    raise MyException1
  
  myFunction2(param1, param2)
  
  ...


IMO there is no need for such a thing because the call stack will show up in the traceback and it's going to do a lot better job than your docstrings to provide the traceback. Otherwise you'd need to go arbitrarily deep and that's not maintainable

There is no official semantics on how to include technical information in a Python docstring (there are formatting recommendations though). Some formats have been created in the context of automated documentation systems like epydoc. If you are using one, see its documentation. If not, you are free to express yourself in a human-understandable way.

Here is a different perspective: if there is too much text to be written in the docstrings and you need a tool to write it, maybe there is something wrong with the functions and it will be too complex to use them. If the user of the function needs to explicitly handle 5 different exception types for each of your functions, you are probably doing something wrong.

Also: read pep8 for naming conventions in python. And also remember that there is no void in python.

@zvone This all follows PEP 8, doesn't it? I mean, assuming the existing codebase uses mixedCase. For void, I could imagine it's a convention that means "this function always returns None and its return value doesn't mean anything."

@roganjosh Documenting the possible exceptions is good for being proactive. I mean, when I'm writing something that uses a function, I want to know what that function might raise so I can plan for it ahead of time, instead of being reactive and only squashing bugs after they've already reared their heads.

@wjandrea I don't disagree with documenting exceptions but it looks like the OP here is going to try document the stack if each sub-function can also throw

@wjandrea Yes, there is a clause in pep8 saying consistency with the rest of the code base overrules pep8. But regardless of that exception, I think I makes sense to point out to pep8, in case the op simply does not know of it.

@zvone: thank you for the hint that void doesn't exists in python, I edited my code samples to return None instead in the docstring...

My coding experience come from different language, therefore void is the first thing that came in my head returning nothing... :-) same here using pascalCase (or mixedCase), it is a habit, but thank you mentioning PEP8, I know now about the conventions, but I'll keep it like this... @all thanks for your opinions, but it seems, there is no convention how to mention recursive raises, I'll think about a solution, that'll fit...
